# unescaped strings inside link - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have this line of code in Laravel

```
{!! Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::link('clients', '<i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Pregled klijenata') !!}
```

When it echoes the href, the part `<i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>` is echoed like a text, but I would like it to be written as a part of html. Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `title` (i.e: `<i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Pregled klijenata`) will be converted to entities.

```
/**
 * Generate a HTML link.
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @param string $title
 * @param array  $attributes
 * @param bool   $secure
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function link($url, $title = null, $attributes = [], $secure = null)
{
    $url = $this->url->to($url, [], $secure);

    if (is_null($title) || $title === false) {
        $title = $url;
    }

    return '<a href="'.$url.'"'.$this->attributes($attributes).'>'.$this->entities($title).'</a>';
}
```

So, you need to convert entities back to HTML characters by:

```
{!! Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::decode(Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::link('clients', '<i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Pregled klijenata')) !!}
```